# How do you Refresh a View from Within A Custom View Class and Call the OnDraw Method?

Tags: java, android-studio

In Android Studio, I have a custom view which is performing two functions. One is to draw when the user touches the screen and the other is to draw when it receives JSON data. The drawing on touch screen is working, but I don't know how to get the view to call the onDraw method when it has finished drawing the path.

I know that it is receiving the data from the console output so it reaches the case statement which sets the path, but onDraw is not called.

Here is the class:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path mPath;
    private ArrayList<PicPoint> points = new ArrayList<PicPoint>();

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        Log.d("DRAW POINTS", "On draw is called.");
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //points = new ArrayList<PicPoint>();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                points.add(new PicPoint(Math.round(event.getX()),Math.round(event.getY()),"s"));
                Log.d("DOWN", String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "," + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                points.add(new PicPoint(Math.round(event.getX()),Math.round(event.getY()),""));
                Log.d("MOVE", String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "," + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                points.add(new PicPoint(Math.round(event.getX()),Math.round(event.getY()),"e"));
                PicturePayload payload = new PicturePayload("2f954fd7-5fe5-40e3-9a26-36be87d0a52f","5504efaf-2bce-4d35-a3a6-fc13105e9e18",points);
                JSONObject picturePayload = payload.getJSONPayload();
                Log.d("UP",picturePayload.toString());
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public void drawPoints(String picData) {
        try {
            JSONArray picArray = new JSONArray(picData);
            for(int i=0;i<picArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject pointJson = picArray.getJSONObject(i);
                PicPoint point = new PicPoint(pointJson.getInt("x"),
                        pointJson.getInt("y"),
                        pointJson.getString("pos")
                );
                Log.d("DRAW POINTS", point.getPos());
                //Draw to canvas
                switch(point.getPos()) {
                    case "s":
                        mPath.moveTo(point.getX(), point.getY());
                        Log.d("DRAW POINTS", "I am drawing the start point");
                    case "e":
                        mPath.lineTo(point.getX(), point.getY());
                        mPath.close();
                    default:
                        mPath.lineTo(point.getX(), point.getY());
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.refreshDrawableState();
    }
}
```

drawPoints is the function called to draw the path to the screen, I know from he following console output that it gets there and has the data, but it doesn't redraw to the screen, onDraw is not called. Can someone help let me know how I get it to call onDraw please or what the correct approach should be?

Console Output:

```
2021-04-30 19:15:19.096 21387-21387/me.uk.picturegame D/DRAW POINTS: On draw is called.
2021-04-30 19:15:24.843 21387-21387/me.uk.picturegame D/DRAW POINTS: s
2021-04-30 19:15:24.843 21387-21387/me.uk.picturegame D/DRAW POINTS: I am drawing the start point
2021-04-30 19:15:24.847 21387-21387/me.uk.picturegame D/DRAW POINTS: e
2021-04-30 19:16:37.614 21387-21387/me.uk.picturegame D/DRAW POINTS: s
2021-04-30 19:16:37.614 21387-21387/me.uk.picturegame D/DRAW POINTS: I am drawing the start point
2021-04-30 19:16:37.616 21387-21387/me.uk.picturegame D/DRAW POINTS: e
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the following works:

replace

```
this.refreshDrawableState();
```

with

```
this.invalidate();
```